# How to know if NuPIC is predicting or repeating?

Tags: nupic

In Matt Taylor's tutorials available at youtube he said that NuPIC firstly repeat what it sees (if it has not enough data) and then start to make predictions. How can I determine from NuPIC csv output which lines were repeated and which were predicted? Thank you